# Flexslider view preview working but not on actual page

Tags: views, javascript

My block is not working for the flexslider: The images are not appearing, but the view preview does work.

I don't know if it is relevant, but a similar problem would happen with just a slideshow view, although one image would appear and it would not cycle.

Could jQuery be a problem?

The following is the actual page with the block that is not showing any images.

> [image]

The following is the view preview, which works.

> [image]

Comment: Fixed it, turns out jquery update module was interfering.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the config of the 'jquery update' module, select 'Default (Provided by Drupal)' in both of the drop-downs.
i.e. 'Default jquery Version' and 'Default jquery Version for administrative pages'