# How to properly configure jQuery for Views Slideshow/Flexslider displays in blocks

Tags: views, javascript

I've been playing with a slider/slide implementation for my site. But don't know how to configure jQuery properly.  My research suggests that this is an issue with the implementation of a jQuery version, but there's conflicting information on how to resolve the problem in the various documentation. I'm aware of both jquery_update and jquery_plugin modules. My current setup have manually loaded libraries for jquery.cycle and Flexslider per their individual documentations. Earlier posts suggest this was a jQuery version conflict.

The issue I have is that the slideshow only cycles in the preview on the page view of the slider. It doesn't cycle in the block view, and it doesn't cycle when it's placed on my page. This the case with both Flexslider and with Views Slideshow. I have the correct modules and libraries, I just don't understand why it works in preview and not when placed on the page.

This post addresses a similar issue [Flexslider view preview working but not on actual page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142447/flexslider-view-preview-working-but-not-on-actual-page), but doesn't really elaborate on how the jquery update conflicts, or how to solve the problem. This post was was flagged as a duplicate so I am trying to articulate what I think I need help with here.

I have searched the documentation on Views Slideshow and Flexslider, and I haven't found an obvious solution to the problem, or a definitive way to address the problem. What seems to be the case is that this is a jQuery versioning issue, where for some reason the javascript isn't initialized from the block itself, but only a page view. I don't know enough about the behavior of javascript in Drupal to understand exactly why one will make the js call, and the other won't?

Comment: Edited to reflect desired clarification.

Comment: Nominated for reopening.  "This question has been asked before *and already has an answer*" is not correct. The supposed duplicate is useless and does not even have a proper answer.

Comment: thnx freeradical!